# How to show message or alert after page reload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using [Jquery Toastr](https://codeseven.github.io/toastr/) to show some success message. It is just like alert for some time.

I want to show some message after page reload. The **problem** is when page is reloaded all javascript is reload.

Is there any way to do this? I want to do this after ajax success.

```
success: function(data) {
    if (data.OperationStatus) {
        window.location.reload(); //Reload the page
        Toaster.show("The record is added"); //I want to show here.But it will never show because when page is loaded javascript is also loaded.            
    }
}
```

Is there any efficient way to do this?

Comment: you have to maintain status in `localStorage`. and get status from `localStorage` if it get success status then show toast.

Comment: Yeah. I am also thinking about it. But is there any event in jquery or in javascript for do this?

Comment: Refer `localstorage` get set  values and if you are facing issue then write here.

Comment: I wonder if you are going to use localStorage how you are going to remove value form it on which event ? because it might be case that you go to another page and come back to same page ..than it that cause your page is new not reloaded page ...

Comment: This is not a problem to remove it. We can check if some key is exist in local storage. Then remove it.

Comment: @Umer - the problem is when you go page first time than you go to another page and come back to page again how you are going to determine...for that he needs to write code in another page load to remove that key..that is only way he can track page is loaded not reloaded..if hope you got my point

Comment: Yes it would be another case but it is sure that the value will set then reload on same page.

Comment: @PranayRana i will set and then intimidate reload the page.I will set in ajax success.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You have to do like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //get it if Status key found
    if(localStorage.getItem("Status"))
    {
        Toaster.show("The record is added");
        localStorage.clear();
    }
});
```

on ajax call set local storage

```
success: function(data) {
if (data.OperationStatus) {
    localStorage.setItem("Status",data.OperationStatus)
    window.location.reload(); 
}
```

You can also do it with `sessionStorage`. Replace `localStorage`  with `sessionStorage` in current code and whole code works with `sessionStorage`.

> On `localStorage` works like cookies get data until you use
>   `localStorage.removeItem(key);` or `localStorage.clear();`
>
> On `sessionStorage`  it remains till you close browser tab or `sessionStorage.removeItem(key);` or `sessionStorage.clear();`.

Check  [Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) for **localStorage** and **sessionStorage** use.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Umer do it like this.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi i have tried this.It works. But actually i asked this question to know is there any other event in javascript or in jquery for reload delay event.I got my answer.Thanks again for your reply.

Comment: for that use `setTimeout`.

Comment: @Umer I think you mean to use `setTimeout(function(){  window.location.reload();  },5000)` in 5sec your `Toaster.show("The record is added");` displays to use and after 5sec page reloads.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi This is possible. but this is not a good approach.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi Localstorage or seesion storage would be the better option

Comment: @Umer `localstorage` remains on browser close and `session storage` get removed automatically on browser close so for that use session storage. Here it is cleared by `localStorage.clear();` so their is not and issue.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi I am using session storage for this.

Comment: @Umer `sessionStorage` remains on current browser tab only. `localStorage` works like `cookies` and you can get in specified path.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi i don't need a new tab that's why i am not using local storage.

Comment: @Umer yes you are write to use `sessionStorage` as per your need.

Comment: Thanks for all conversation @ParthTrivedi